# PhoneGap Capture API calls onFail function when back key is pressed in Android

Tags: android, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using PhoneGap Media Capture API to capture audio from native recorder. In android, when back button is pressed it calls the onFail function. Is there any way how to avoid the function call on back key press event?

Answer (score 0):

My understand from reading the [Capture API documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/cordova_media_capture_capture.md.html#Capture), is that it is the expected behavior for the `captureError` function to be invoked in this scenario:

> This function executes if an error occurs when trying to launch a
>   media capture operation. Failure scenarios include when the capture
>   application is busy, a capture operation is already taking place, or
>   the user cancels the operation before any media files are captured.

What is your expectation? What are you trying to do otherwise?
I don't think this can be overridden.